# $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the countable intersection of open sets. Is my Reasoning Correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question has actually 2 parts. I know the question has been asked before, but I want to know if my reasoning makes sense.I've done the first part but am unsure about the second. It goes as follows:

$\text{1) Show that} \ (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})  \ \text{is not the countable union of of closed sets}  \\ \text{2) Show that} \ (\mathbb{Q}) \ \text{is not the countable intersection of open sets}$

First I should ask: Can I just argue that as the countable union of closed sets is closed and since $(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})$ is neither open nor closed the statement would make no sense?  (an analogous case could be used in the $\mathbb{Q}$ part.

My second question is: For the second part, not using the argument above but using the first part of the problem, is it correct to say that
$$ (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcup_ {n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n \text{ , where $C_n$ is a closed set $\Rightarrow$ }$$
$$(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^c \neq (\bigcup_ {n\in\mathbb{N} } C_n)^c  \text{ , where little c is the complement}\Rightarrow  $$
$$(\mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcap_ {n\in\mathbb{N} } (C_n)^c =\bigcap_ {n\in\mathbb{N}} O_n \text{ , where $O_n$ is an open set, which would prove part 2?} $$

Comment: The countable union of closed sets is not closed. The finite union of closed sets is closed.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you!